# Implicit parameter does not work

Tags: scala, implicits

Suppose that I have the following scala code:

```
trait ValueSource[A] {
  def value(a: Int): A
}

trait ValueSourceOps[A] {
  def self: Int
  def F: ValueSource[A]
  def value: A = F.value(self)
}

trait ToValueSourceOps {
  implicit def toValueSourceOps[A](index: Int)(implicit F0: ValueSource[A]): ValueSourceOps[A] =    new ValueSourceOps[A] {
    def self = index
    def F: ValueSource[A] = F0
  }
}

object Test extends ToValueSourceOps {
  def value[A: ValueSource](index: Int): A = toValueSourceOps(index).value
}
```

The code above compiles well, but when I change the last line (body of method "value" in object Test) to

```
def value[A: ValueSource](index: Int): A = index.value
```

the compiler complains that 
    could not find implicit value for parameter F0: ValueSource[A]

In my opinion, def value[A: ValueSource] means I have a implicit value "ValueSource[A]", then why does the compilation fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `A` in `toValueSourceOps` has *no* relationship with the `A` in `value`, which makes inferring it problematic. To me the real question is why it works when you call the method explicitly.

I'm guessing that, when `toValueSourceOp` is called explicitly, it *has* to infer the same `A` because that's the only implicit available.